# Microsoft Graph - recent endpoint not returning recently used files

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/drive-recent?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) `/me/drive/recent` endpoint returns the list of recently used items by the signed in user.

However, regardless of the activity of the user, I couldn't get the list of recent files. I keep seeing the same response: empty response for personal account and some items that are unrelated to the user's activity for business account.

There is another [enpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/insights-list-used?view=graph-rest-beta) `/me/insights/used` that returns exactly what I need. However, it is under beta and, what is more, it works only for business account.

How do I get recent files for both personal and business account?
Is there something wrong with `/me/drive/recent` endpoint?

Comment: Could you please check if you have any files in "Recent" of your personal account Onedrive on https://onedrive.live.com/?wt.mc_id=oo_msn_msnhomepage_header? If there is nothing in it, you will get empty response for personal account.

Comment: @AllenWu There are no files in "Recent" for my personal account. But why? What files are displayed in "Recent"?

Comment: Previously, I created some documents, edited them, shared one and uploaded files. I opened them and edited one by one. The "Recent" page is still empty.